# Flutter type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Product>

Tags: http, flutter, dart

This is my products provider:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import '../models/Product.dart';

class Products with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Product> _items = [];

  List<Product> get items {
    return [..._items];
  }

  Future<void> getProducts() async {
    try {
      final response =
          await Dio().get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
      final List<Product> body = response.data;
      _items = body;
      notifyListeners();
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

And then, this is my Product model:

```
class Product {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String body;
  final String userId;

  Product({this.id, this.title, this.body, this.userId});

  factory Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Product(
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
      body: json['body'],
      userId: json['userId'],
    );
  }
}
```

However, in `getProducts()` function, if I assign `_items` to `response.data`, it says

> 'List' is not a subtype of type 'List'.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, actually I had to install `Dio` package to check what's going wrong with your code. I tested this and **it is 100% working** now.

```
class Products with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Product> _items = [];

  List<Product> get items {
    return [..._items];
  }

  Future<void> getProducts() async {
    try {
      final response = await Dio().get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");

      // change this
      final List<dynamic> body = response.data;
      for (var data in body) {
        _items.add(Product.fromJson(data));
      }
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}

class Product {
  final int id; // change this
  final String title;
  final String body;
  final int userId; // and this

  Product({this.id, this.title, this.body, this.userId});

  factory Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Product(
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
      body: json['body'],
      userId: json['userId'],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't let me assign if I do this: `final List<dynamic> body = response.data; _items = body;`. It always says `Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Product>'`.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! Also thanks for pointing out the stupid mistakes.